# Code for accessing windows registry throwing error

Tags: java

I have a chunk of code which is called at my application startup to find the `ProgramData` folder of the users PC and to create the `application.log` file for my app.

Problem is that in one of the users PC having windows 7, its throwing `nullpoint` error in the Java tracing pop up.
I am not sure how to recreate or debug this issue, as this is the step to create the log file and put in ProgramData folder.

Any help is really appreciated!

```
    final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
    final int KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 1;
    final Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
    final Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
    final Class clz = userRoot.getClass();
    String appData = null;
    try {
        Method openKey = clz.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",
                new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class, int.class });
        openKey.setAccessible(true);
        Method closeKey = clz.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey",
                new Class[] { int.class });
        closeKey.setAccessible(true);
        Method queryKey = clz.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx",
                new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });
        queryKey.setAccessible(true); 
        int[] result = (int[]) openKey
                .invoke(
                        systemRoot,
                        new Object[] {
                                new Integer(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE),
                                toCstr("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders"),
                                new Integer(KEY_QUERY_VALUE) });
    int handle = result[0];
    if(handle!=0){
        byte[] bytes =(byte[]) queryKey.invoke(
                systemRoot,
                new Object[] {
                        handle,
                        toCstr("Common AppData")});
        appData = new String(bytes,"US-ASCII");
        closeKey.invoke(systemRoot,new Object[]{handle});
    }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        //log.error(e1.getStackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: More information what happened would have been in the exception stack trace (which you decided to ignore in your catch clause)

Comment: If you fail in the process of finding the appropriate location for the log file, you could display a file-chooser, and ask the user to select the location to save the log. (Or pick a default, like ${HOMEDRIVE}${HOMEPATH} or ${APPDATA} or C:\temp\) --- that will at least let you log the stack trace to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thomas i commented just for this post even if i just put e1.getStackTrace(), where it will show the details? And even if i keep the stackTrace it will just show the null[pointer exception. Currently its not showing which line is having nullpointer exception.

Comment: What library do you use for calling WindowsAPI methods/registry access?

Comment: There is no such thing as a '`nullpoint` error'.